# Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: no existe la función date

Tags: php, postgresql, php5

En mi archivo `paginador_ini.php` en la *línea 10*, tengo el siguiente código:

```
$datos=pg_query($consulta); 
$num_rows=pg_num_rows($datos); // Miro cuantos datos fueron devueltos
$rows_per_page= $tam; // Se decide cuantos resultados mostrar por pagina
$lastpage= ceil($num_rows / $rows_per_page); // Calculo la ultima pagina
$page=(int)$page; // Compruebo que el valor de la pagina sea correcto y si es la ultima pagina
```

La variable `$consulta` llega desde un *SQL* escrito de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($conex=conexion()){
    $word = $_GET['word'];
    $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id_archivo, a.nombre AS narchivo, a.titulo_articulo, a.fecha, b.nombre AS ncategoria, a.prioridad
        FROM archivos AS a
        INNER JOIN categorias AS b 
        ON a.id_categoria = b.id_categoria
        WHERE estatus = 1 AND 
        (a.nombre LIKE '%$word%' OR b.nombre LIKE '%$word%' 
         OR a.titulo_articulo LIKE '%$word%'OR DATE(a.fecha,'%d-%m-%Y') LIKE '%$word%' 
         OR a.palabra LIKE '%$word%') 
         ORDER BY a.id_archivo DESC";
    $tam = 15;
    list($exec,$numrows,$page,$lastpage) = paginador_ini($consulta,$tam);
}
```

¿Cómo se puede corregir el error? Sé que tiene relación con el tipo de datos, pero no entiendo por qué. El dato que estoy queriendo consultar es precisamente una fecha.

El error es el siguiente:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: no existe la función
>   `date(timestamp without time zone, unknown)`
>   LINE 4: ..`.nombre LIKE '%%' OR a.titulo_articulo LIKE '%%'OR DATE(a.fec... ^`
>   HINT: Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\OvamExtranet\Vistas\paginador_ini.php on line 10

Comment: De entrada, tienes un error ortográfico aquí: `'%$word%'OR` **falta un espacio antes de `OR`**.

Comment: Gracias, un buen detalle de tu parte. Pero sigue el mismo error.

Comment: Me parece que postgresql no tiene una función `DATE`, [ver funciones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) y ver ejemplos de sintaxis: `SELECT (DATE '2001-02-16', DATE '2001-12-21') ...` mientras que tú escribes `DATE (...)` como si fuese una función.

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a chequear eso.

Comment: Quizá lo que necesites es una función como [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) que sirve para convertir y dar formato a fechas.

Comment: hay algo extraño estas comparando un string con un date?? puedes imprimir la consulta con los datos obtenidos para que la visualicemos mejor

Comment: La solucion fué usar la funcion to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, solo me guié de la documentación de *PostgreSQL* y para este caso debía usar la función `to_char`.

[PostgreSQL Documentation: 9.4. Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)